# QT enable cross-compiling using MinGW (precompiled)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling

Good day all

I have been searching for a method of cross-compiling for QT-Creator in Linux for sometime now, and I have been having alot of trouble with it.

**Background info**

*please note: I am on a Linux machine, and would like to cross compile Windows Apps*

My system:

- Ubuntu Gnome 16.10
- QT Creator 4.0.2 (based on QT 5.7)

I have came across a few SO [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011845/can-qt-creator-on-linux-create-exe-files/1011856#1011856), a few blogs with broken instructions, etc and [one](http://silmor.de/qtstuff.mingw.php) seeming helpful but dependencies could not be found.

I have also attempted another compiler [MXE](https://mxe.cc/) and cloned and attempted to build the MXE compiler from the GIT [repo](https://github.com/mxe/mxe), which failed (no solution for the build error - VTK build error)

I decided to download [precompiled MinGW compilers](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Automated%20Builds/) (i686 and x86_x64 versions) from sourceforge

**Issue:**

In QT Creator, adding the compiler is done without an issue, adding the "Kit" and selecting the newly added compiler, an red exclamation gives an error

> The Compiler (x86_windows_msys_pe_64bit) cannot produce code for QT version 5.7.0 GCC 64Bit (x86_linux_generic_elf_64bit)

*This occurs for both 32 + 64 bit compilers.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have a QT version that matches your compiler ABI. The error tells you that the MinGW compiler doesn't match the Linux version of QT you have used. Therefore, get a windows version of QT and use it instead (just as you've added WinGW).

You can download Qt Binaries from [here](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/).

Comment: thank you for the response, I have GCC 6 install, and the MinGW compiler uses `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 6.2.0 20160822`, although QT-Creator uses GCC 4.9, if QT-Creator 4.0.2 (based on QT 5.7) uses GCC 4.9, should I attempt at building QT-Creator 4.0.2 with GCC 6 ?

Comment: @KGCybeX You should get a windows version of Qt. If you want, you can build Qt for Windows with MinGW and use it.

Comment: That is exactly what I didn't want, I would like to compile `.exe`'s within Linux, thus avoid booting into Windows.

Comment: @KGCybeX No, you should have Qt libraries for windows on Linux in order to compile a Qt program for Windows.

Comment: thank you for the advice, to conclude, any idea how I should include the libraries? Should I place them in the relevant linux directories (same dir as linux lib for each respective windows lib) or should this be added to  the compiler lib structure?

Comment: @KGCybeX Try to add it as a Qt version (almost the same way as adding the MinGW compiler).